# What is an event's “raise” accessor in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, events, roslyn

Roslyn's [`IEventSymbol`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Roslyn.Compilers.Common/Roslyn.Compilers/IEventSymbol) provides convenient access to all the relevant parts of an event declaration. While `AddMethod` and `RemoveMethod` are simple enough to understand, I am not sure what the `RaiseMethod` should be. Documentation is a bit parse as well.

The C# specification only mentions add and remove accessors for events. Is this perhaps something that other CLR languages allow to specify?

Comment: Is that not just what the containing class calls to... raise the event?

Comment: Since the accessor is usually `null` and C#'s specification just mentions that the backing field of delegate type will be invoked ... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/EventSymbol.cs,327) in the Roslyn source:

```
internal abstract partial class EventSymbol : Symbol, IEventSymbol
{
    ...

    IMethodSymbol IEventSymbol.RaiseMethod
    {
        get
        {
            // C# doesn't have raise methods for events.
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

It looks like it's actually something that applies to [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx):

> An event is like a message announcing that something important has occurred. The act of broadcasting the message is called raising the event. In Visual Basic, you raise events with the RaiseEvent statement, as in the following example:
>
> `RaiseEvent AnEvent(EventNumber)`
>
> Events must be raised within the scope of the class, module, or structure where they are declared. For example, a derived class cannot raise events inherited from a base class.

Looking in the [Roslyn source for VB](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic/Symbols/EventSymbol.vb,336f6173ded18efb,references), there are a *lot* more references to that `RaiseMethod` property.

The VB specification mentions the `RaiseEvent` accessor explicitly in section 9.4.1 *Custom Events:*

> Custom events are declared in the same way that events that specify a
>   delegate type are declared, with the exception that the keyword `Custom`
>   must precede the `Event` keyword. A custom event declaration contains
>   three declarations: an `AddHandler` declaration, a `RemoveHandler`
>   declaration **and a `RaiseEvent` declaration**. None of the declarations can
>   have any modifiers, although they can have attributes. For example:
>
> ```vb
> Class Test
>     Private Handlers As EventHandler
>
>     Public Custom Event TestEvent As EventHandler
>         AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
>             Handlers = CType([Delegate].Combine(Handlers, value), _
>                 EventHandler)
>         End AddHandler
>
>         RemoveHandler(value as EventHandler)
>             Handlers = CType([Delegate].Remove(Handlers, value), _
>                 EventHandler)
>         End RemoveHandler
>
>         RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
>             Dim TempHandlers As EventHandler = Handlers
>
>             If TempHandlers IsNot Nothing Then
>                 TempHandlers(sender, e)
>             End If
>         End RaiseEvent
>     End Event
> End Class
> ```

Comment: Ah, indeed. The VB spec in §9.4.1 mentions all three accessors. I edited that part in, if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Joey You just inspired me to open the VB spec for the first time ever. I'm not sure I'll do it again... (and ty for the edit!)

Comment: Aww, come on. There are far worse ones out there. ECMA-262 comes to mind, for example ;-)

Comment: BTW, the raise accessor has support directly in IL, see §II.22.13 and §II.23.1.12 or ECMA-335. I think that's more relevant than 262 here. :-)